# Links is not centered in the fixed navigation

Tags: html, css

I want my navigation links to be centered in my fixed navigation bar i tried to
adding padding but somehow the navigation expands. Also i tried to vertical-align but that didn't do much. I am really new to CSS so explanations would be helpful in cases if this happened again

*HTML*

```
`<html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Photography | Home </title>
        <link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="on.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <header>
            <div id="branding">
                <h2>PHOTOGRAPHY</h2>
            </div>
            <nav id="links">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PHOTO GALLERY</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">VIDEO GALLERY</a></li>
            </ul>
                </nav>
        </header>
        <section id="showcase">
            <div class="container">
            <h2>Photography</h2>
            <p>Our photo's are always presente in the best
                quality possible with carefulness
            </p>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="boxes">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="box">asdasdsada
                    <img src="./images/CameraIcon.png">
                    <h2>Photography</h2>
                    <p>Our photographers will always find the perfect photo whether it is a simple click to a full on video</p>
                </div>
                      <div class="box">
                            <img src="./images/CommunityICON.jpg">
                            <h2>Guranteed!</h2>
                            <p>If you are not satisfied with our work you will have an 80% refund</p>


                </div>
                      <div class="box">
                            <img src="./images/TimeIcon.png">
                            <h2>Time Managment</h2>
                            <p>Time management is a crucial step so we are always trying our best to finish up the work quickly, but surely</p>

                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <footer>
            <p>Note that any copyright &copy; is reserved</p>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>`
```

*CSS*

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden
}
header {
    background-color: #191919;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    color: #edf9ff;
    min-height: 70px;
    border-bottom: #0fe216 3px solid;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
header a {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
header ul {
    margin: 0;
}
header li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float:right;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
nav {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: you want them centered vertically?

Comment: yea i want it centered vertically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `display: flex`. It makes this really easy. Use `align-items: center;` to center vertically and `justify-content: space-between` to separate the logo from the nav. Then I would also float your nav `li`'s left, so they're in order. You could use `flex` there, too, but isn't necessary.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden
}

header {
  background-color: #191919;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  color: #edf9ff;
  min-height: 70px;
  border-bottom: #0fe216 3px solid;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

header ul {
  margin: 0;
}

header li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

nav {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Photography | Home </title>
  <link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script type="application/javascript" src="on.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div id="branding">
      <h2>PHOTOGRAPHY</h2>
    </div>
    <nav id="links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PHOTO GALLERY</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">VIDEO GALLERY</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <section id="showcase">
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Photography</h2>
      <p>Our photo's are always presente in the best quality possible with carefulness
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="boxes">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="box">asdasdsada
        <img src="./images/CameraIcon.png">
        <h2>Photography</h2>
        <p>Our photographers will always find the perfect photo whether it is a simple click to a full on video</p>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <img src="./images/CommunityICON.jpg">
        <h2>Guranteed!</h2>
        <p>If you are not satisfied with our work you will have an 80% refund</p>


      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <img src="./images/TimeIcon.png">
        <h2>Time Managment</h2>
        <p>Time management is a crucial step so we are always trying our best to finish up the work quickly, but surely</p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <footer>
    <p>Note that any copyright &copy; is reserved</p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```